# How to clone root user in Ubuntu?

Tags: users, root

What is the procedure of cloning the root user in Ubuntu? How is root cloning useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there is no root user in Ubuntu. Root account is disabled with blank password.

If you want make another user with administrative rights just go to System Settings -> User Accounts, make new user there and select account type "Administrator" instead "Custom" or "Desktop user". Do not forget set password for new user to make it enabled.